# What are the ISCG05 bolt dimensions?

Tags: mountain-bike

What are the dimensions for bolts meant to be used with ISCG05 chain devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the official [standard](https://www.iscg.org/iscg-05_standard.pdf).
It says M6×1 for the mounting holes.

[image: ICSG 05 drawing]